# Android Firebase: How to get a list of object from inside an object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have inside each `object` a list of object how to get the values of the inner `arraylist`.Like here I want to get the values inside the book list.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find the **solution**

[image: Database View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the values inside `books`, try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     DataSnapshot ds=datas.child("books");
     for (DataSnapshot dsBook: ds.getChildren()) {
      String bookName=dsBook.child("book_Name").getValue().toString();
    }
 }
  @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
   });
```

Snapshot is at `User`, then you iterate inside it's direct children and access the child `books`. Then you iterate again, but this time inside the snapshot which is `books` and get the values `book_Name`, `book_Status`